# Cached images are missing from frontend and product pages

Tags: product-images, media, media-images

Certain images are missing from my frontend. The cached image location seems to be wrong however all the rest of the images are there and intact. I am just wondering why those images are not automatically generated upon visiting the product page? The issue is that I have 50K images if I generate those using bin/magento catalog:images:resize command it will take forever.

Comment: "seems to be wrong" please verify this assumption

Comment: if I look for the image it is there but the hash is different than the one that should load on the page?

Comment: the rewrite is in the pub/media/.htaccess file, maybe you accidentally deleted that file?

Comment: Nah, it is all there :(

Answer (score 1):

The issue was permissions. The permissions on `./var/resource_config.json` were incorrect. The webserver didn't have write permissions.